# rewrite url with parameters in .htaccess

Tags: php, url-rewriting, .htaccess

I have this incoming url where the last part is dynamic.

```
https://www.rishi.com/q/CuYuGy
```

and want to rewrite the url to below link.

```
https://rishi.com/test.php
```

where it gets the dynamic part and performs action

so far i have done this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^rishi.com/q/%{QUERY_STRING}$
RewriteRule ^$ {HTTP_HOST} ^rishi.com/test.php [L,R=301]
```

please help me resolve it.
Thanks

Comment: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^rishi.com/q/%{QUERY_STRING}$` – so apparently you don’t know what “host name” means, maybe start by looking that up then.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
RewriteRule ^q/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ test.php?query_string=$1
RewriteRule ^q/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/$ test.php?query_string=$1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this below htaccess code. It should help you

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/q/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /test.php [L,R=301]
```